# Is send_resp() and put_resp_content_type() the canonical way to send a string as XML in Phoenix?

Tags: xml, elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix, what's the canonical way of sending a string as an XML response?

I have the following code which works fine, but it seems like I should use render or similar?

```
conn
|> put_resp_content_type("text/xml")
|> send_resp(200, some_string_with_xml)
```

Is there a better or more canonical way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe there's a more "idiomatic" way of doing it. There's a helper to do something similar for JSON (Phoenix.Controller.json/2), but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.1/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L182) it's doing essentially what you're doing there. There's nothing out-of-the-box for XML as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Phoenix there isn't directly support to xml so you need to fall back to what [plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug) expose. As you can see in the hello world example in [README](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/2df667389dbaebb0e2102343c8d7a6ed4de6e280/README.md#hello-world) this is the classical way.

```
defmodule MyPlug do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    # initialize options

    options
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "Hello world")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference!